# Ajax, handling the php response in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

So I'm learning Ajax and I followed this tutorial: https://phpacademy.org/course/submitting-a-form-with-ajax to create a function that works for any form. This is the complete function:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            alert(url + ' ' + response);
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

As you see all I'm doing is alerting the response, which in this case is php `echo`. That's where my problem starts, I need a flexible and secure way to handle the javascript/php communication. Preferrably one function for all forms, maybe with `if ()` statements instead of `alert(url + ' ' + response);` depending on the form `url`.

The function I need is not very complicated, based on the response I get I will just update the current form with errors.

Aslong as I know what to use in the communication I'm fine from there, `echo '1';` as I have now doesn't feel like the ideal solution but it's all I could handle.

So, what type of response should I send from the php page, and where (in the javascript) and how is the best way to handle it? I've heard of json but having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Could someone show a json response sending a basic integer thats easy for my response to pick up as an int?

Comment: Simple JSON response `{ response : 1 }` - Accessed as `response.response` (I typically use `data` as my param name in the success callback, but that's all preference)

Comment: I tried getting it to work but I only get undefined back. In the php I did `if () { response : 1}` tried with semi-colon and everything I could think of, and in the js I do `success: function(response) {
   alert(url + ' ' + response.response);
  }`

Comment: You'll have to `json_encode` your data on the PHP side. (Assuming your type is `json`.

Comment: Guess I have to watch a simple json tutorial, change your comment to an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send back a simple JSON response via PHP and check it in your `success` callback. Make sure you're setting the `type` to `json` and in your AJAX call, and using `json_encode` on the PHP side:

```
$response = array('response' => 1);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Output should be:

```
{ 'response' : 1 }
```

Comment: Don't forget, `header('Content-type: application/json');`